# The cost function of LS algorithm

Tags: ofdm, frequency-domain, equalization, least-squares

I'm trying to understand the derivation of LS algorithm for channel estimation in OFDM.

Could anyone explain why do we need complex conj transpose in the below equation?
[image: LS]

Answer (score 2):

Because **when a quantity can be complex**, and even when it is just real, the absolute squared difference $|f-g|^2$ can be expressed in both domain (complex and real) as:

$$|f-g|^2 = (f-g)^H(f-g)$$
and of course this is correct as well for reals. This setting is often related to [Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space).